# Azure provisioning state failed, how to reset

Tags: networking, azure

I tried deleting a subnet from my Azure Vnet, but that failed. THen I figured out how to just change the mask length of the subnet, so I don't need to delete it anymore. 
Problem is, the entire network is now marked as "failed" and I can't do anything to it because of that state.

So, how can I "reset" it to a successful state without deleting it?

Answer (score 1):

Why is your VNET stuck into the failed status?

If the configuration of your VNET are correct, then you can try to follow the steps below to refresh the status of your VNET:

1. Get the VNET : **$vnet = Get-AzureRmVirtualNetwork -Name** *VNET_Name* **-ResourceGroupName** *Resource_Group_Name*
2. Reconfigure the VNET: **Set-AzureRmVirtualNetwork -VirtualNetwork $vnet**

If the reconfiguration still fails, then please check the configuration of your VNET, correct it and reconfigure it again.

Comment: It failed because I tried deleting a subnet. That subnet recently contained an ER gateway, which was why deleting the subnet failed.
So, the config of the vnet didn't actually change as the deletion failed.

I was able to delete-readd the subnet after waiting a few hours.